# Array Not populating for column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the below in google sheets to check whether or not columns have been populated with data. However It's filling Yes for the entire column and I only have sample values in the first row.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(AC:AC)=1,"Has Certificate Been Generated?",ArrayFormula(if(and(AC:AC="",AG:AG="",AK:AK="",AO:AO=""),"No","Yes"))))
```

Thoughts?

TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AND() in an ArrayFormula like that. Try something like this instead:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  if(
    row(AC:AC)=1,
    "Has Certificate Been Generated?",
    if((AC:AC="")*(AG:AG="")*(AK:AK="")*(AO:AO=""),
      "No",
      "Yes"
    )
  )
)
```